# Updating alternate colors of dynamic/ajax table rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table, row, alternate

Been looking lot but couldn't find, apply alternate row colors via jQuery on `$(document).ready` event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    //Member Directory Table  
    $('.MemberDetail table tr:odd ').css('background','#F0F0EC');  
}
```

colors applied, but when table is updated with ajax request, it doesn't update colors. So what could be the better way to apply alternate colors to that table?

There's an example on this page:

[**Here Dynamic Table**](http://kcci.com.pk/Members/MembersSearch.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You should use this script when Ajax is Complete. I mean something like

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    //to do your jQuery code again;
    $('.MemberDetail table tr:odd ').css('background','#F0F0EC');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to execute the table color function again, after the ajax request

```
function ajax() {
doAjaxStuff();

$('.MemberDetail table tr:odd ').css('background','#F0F0EC');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update the table again:

```
$('.MemberDetail table').find('tr:odd').css('background','#F0F0EC').end().find('tr:even').css('background','#fff');
```

There's no magic way to automatically maintain those colours, just have to update each time you update the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `CSS` class like this one for example:

```
.alternate
{
    background: #e6f4ff;
}
```

to apply an alternate color to table rows, it's easier... after doing some `jQuery` to add table rows dynamically, you can do something like this:

```
$("table tbody tr").removeClass("alternate").filter(":odd").addClass("alternate");
```

This should keep the rows colored correctly no matter what you do: be it adding or removing `<table>` rows.

Just remember you'll have to always run the code every time the `<table>` gets modified.